# Air for android StageWebView issue

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, apk, stagewebview

I'm currently creating an app that has a stagewebview to display the contents of a website. When i load this page in the normal android browser i get the authentication popup which allows the user to login as shown below :

[image: This is on the browser]

When i test the movie in flash cc pro, this is what i get :

[image]

But when i put the APK on to the device and play it, there is no sign in dialog, it is just going straight to the not authorized page without giving me the option to sign in.

Can anyone help me out with this im pretty stuck on a fix.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The stagewebview differences are mentioned in the following blogpost
https://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/stagewebview-differences-platforms-air-sdk.html

It clearly says

```
**HTTP authentication dialog is not implemented on mobile (iOS/Android)**

Currently no default UI is implemented on mobile for HTTP authentication. On
desktop HTTP authentication uses the default OS dialog for authentication. 
Event though the authentication dialog is disabled, the developer can create 
their own UI and use the URLRequest API to do basic or digest authentication.
```